# Sim card locked

Tags: lumia, networking

I'd like to ask a question about the icon on the top left.

[image: Sim locked icon]

I've read on a WP8 board that's a locked sim icon, but why my phone locks the simcard ?
The only way I found to unlock the card is:
1- go to parameters -> phone -> switch from automatic network selection to manual and back again (the phone ask me to insert the pin and here I go)
2- turn of/on the device

Someone can tell me for what reason this happens ?

I own a Lumia 820 with the last update available.

Comment: I have this same issue. My Nokia Lumia 820 locks the sim all by itself a couple times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your device is pin locked by your SIM and you want to disable it.

1.
On StartStart icon, tap Phone Phone tile > More (...) icon > Settings.

2.
Turn off SIM Toggle switch.

It will stops to ask for your SIM pin.

Comment: the question is why it's simlocked ? Sometimes I put it in my pocket and 10 minutes later it's locked, I'd just know why and, eventually, how entering pin code without the heavy preference manipulation descripted above

Comment: What you mean is that you or another person never turn this option on and it turns on by their own?

Comment: yup, the option turns on by its own

Answer (score 1):

I had a sim lock after an update to 8.0.10532.166 with my Nokia Lumia 620. I could not shut the phone down nor unlock it. After 15 minutes I deceided to take out the battery. After that the phone worked fine again.

Comment: I see that the problem still happens without reason, I asked microsoft and they couldn't answer me, guess it'll stay a mistery forever. Since then I've decided to go back to HTC, no more problems :)